# Additional fields in Wagtail User Edit

Tags: django, wagtail

I have extended my user model with the OneToOne model and would now like to be able to change additional information via the Wagtail user editing interface.

```
Customers App
#customer.model
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='customers')
    org_title = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True)
```

[image]

I have already seen this topic in wagtail docs: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.9.3/advanced_topics/customisation/custom_user_models.html
But AbstractUser models are used. How can this be achieved with related models through the OneToOne relationship?